# Menu item is nor dispalying Dialog box eventhough no errors

Tags: android

menu item is not displaying dialog box below is my code when user click on menu item it should take him to login page where to add that code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item, int id) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Login:
             startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
             return true;
        case R.id.About:
         startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.Post_Ads:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
             return true;


          }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: try adding break; in the end of the case.

Comment: adding break in end of case then not no dialog box appearing

Comment: "no dialog box appearing", what do you mean here.  You had a "Are you sure you want to exit?" dialog box whether you mean this one or something else?... Whether you mean menu dialog with Login,About, Exit is not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , it should work:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Login:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fired 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                 return true;

            case R.id.About:
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fired 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));

                return true;
                        case R.id.Post_Ads:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                       .setCancelable(false);
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));

                 return true;


              }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```

There is no method called `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item, int id)` in the `Activity` `class` to `handle option menu's.`

The method to handle such events is   `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`.

For your menu items to getting displayed, you have to use following method too,
Check whether you have implemented this method also or not,

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And a small correction,

You have implemented the following Alertdialog method,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
```

You haven't provided any ok or cancel button here,
And also you made it setCancellable(false). So User cannot choose any options here.

So i am suggesting you to give Ok and Cancel Button here and do what you want to do inside the onClick() method. Like the following example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do call some activity or close the app. Do what you wish to;

                }
            });

alert.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do stay in the current activity or something else. Do what you wish to;

                }
            });
                    alert.show();

             return true;
```

Hope, It might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you it works, but dialog box disappears immediately within a fraction of second

Comment: Good... Do well. Don't forgot to accept the answer and an upvote.

Comment: "dialog box disappears immediately within a fraction of second" Can't get you. Which dialog box? When it disappers, whether after click happens on somewhere or appears and disappears automatically?..

Comment: without clicking anything dialog box disappears and it goes to login page

Comment: Have u tried by copy the above code. And if you can paste your menu.xml file here...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Navigate to login").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do things
                           startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
                       }
                   });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```